# Lowest output resolution for external display in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, vga

I am trying to plug into an external display through a VGA -> Component and need the resolution to be lower than 800x600...is this even possibly with Mountain Lion?

Comment: It depends on the graphic card. Are you connecting the external display to a desktop (Mac Pro) or to a notebook (MacBook/Pro/Air)? Which model *exactly*?

Comment: 13' MacBook Pro mid-2010

Graphics  NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

Comment: According to http://support.apple.com/kb/SP583 you can get as low a resolution as 640x480 for the *internal* display. I guess you should simply try it, if the display supports such a low resolution the graphic card will play along.

Comment: http://www.lastnightshype.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/resolutions.png

Those are the only options I have as far as internal display.

Comment: So you can't get a lower resolution than 800x600, which kind of invalidates my previous comment. You may find this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHi6RMM4_6I useful, which explains how to set a custom resolution.